# Get all orders of customer using customer's token in Magento 2 API

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api

I want **all orders** of customer **using customer's Token** in Magento API.

Which gives the list of all previous orders of the customer.

This API provides me the cart products of specific customer using customer's Token.

```
http://<magento-host>/rest/V1/carts/mine

Authorization :: Bearer <Customer Token>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please elaborate how did you achieved it?

Comment: Yes of-cause, can you please ask the question for the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the **solution** For this!!

Magento is using resource `Magento_Sales::sales` because of this we can't access it using **Customer's token** so for the same we need to **override** Specific **API** with

`<resource ref="self" />`

And using this we can access all orders of specific customer using **customer's Token** in Magento API.

```
<route url="/V1/orders" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self" />
        </resources>
    </route>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to filter out the orders of a single customer using the search query parameters like this:

```
https://<mage host>/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters]
[0][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=<customer_id>
```

This returns a list of orders on which you can loop and find out other information.

Comment: Okay, What i am supposed to put in [filterGroups] and [filters]

Comment: That is just syntax, you just have to put the customer_id where is <customer_id>
https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#!/salesOrderRepositoryV1

Comment: Okay, let me try :)

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/rb-dev/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters]
[0][field]=160&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=160

Comment: And i also passed customer token in Authorization :: Bearer <Customer Token>

Comment: But gives me error  "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",

Comment: This endpoint requires admin privileges and won’t work with customer token

Comment: ok first, the first customer_id do not have to be substituted, only the second one, included in <>.
The exception is given because you have to specify which resources are accessible to users with API

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/rb-dev/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters]
[0][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=160

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`` = '160'))",

Comment: that is what i told in previous comment: your request must be:

`http://127.0.0.1/rb-dev/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=160`

Comment: Okay, thanks alot but i need data using customer's token, this requires Admin token

Comment: I want all orders of customer using customer's Token

Comment: But, thanks alot for your efforts !! @sissy :) + decuplet

Comment: oh sorry i did not understand it was the only data you have at your disposal. actually i'm not sure it is possible ...i'll have a look and just in case, i will update my answer. Hope just to have helped to save some time ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78528/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-sissy).

Comment: @sissy API throws error.
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`` = '2'))",
    "code": 42,

Answer (score 2):

I think Magento2 doesn't provide inbuilt functionality for customer token to fetch all orders so you need to implement the same.

And for that, kindly refer below link

```
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167749/get-pending-completed-processing-orders-rest-api-problem

http://www.ipragmatech.com/extend-magento2-rest-api-easy-steps/
```