# How can we get customer orders history with rest API

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, api, magento2.3.1

How can we get the customer order history over the rest API with the customer token.

If I'm trying the url

```
/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=bob@fett.com&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like
```

I'm getting this:

```
{
    "message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "Magento_Sales::actions_view"
    },
    "trace": "#0 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator.php(68): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator->checkPermissions()\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(80): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator->validate()\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver->resolve()\n#3 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->___callParent('resolve', Array)\n#4 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#5 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('resolve', Array, Array)\n#6 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(85): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->resolve()\n#7 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#8 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#9 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#10 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#11 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#12 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(136): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#13 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#14 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#15 /var/www/vhosts/store-api.silverwax.ca/httpdocs/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#16 {main}"
}
```

I've tried to the proposal of [@aaditya](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/63138/aaditya) in the [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228815/get-all-orders-of-customer-using-customers-token-in-magento-2-api) but it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend the rest API endpoint of orders(which is originally customer has no access) in order to access it using customer's token, You have to create a **`custom endpoint`** as well otherwise the endpoint **`/V1/orders`** will still inaccessible for the customer.
Check below example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/orders/custom" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

And you can use the custom endpoint **`/V1/orders/custom`** to get orders list of the customer using customer's token.

Comment: Thanks, It's change my error with the authorization but now the `getLIst` method recived the customer ID as OrderID.

Comment: I check with mine but it gives me correct result

Comment: like this `/rest/V1/orders/custom?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=5&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like`

Comment: I've tryied this too and it wasn't working. Finally I've found a plugin who did the job for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @maru3l What is that plugin ?? Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

@fmsthird is correct in regards having to create a custom endpoint, however I resorted to creating a new class that depends on `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` rather than calling that class directly. From there I've created a new method that the endpoint utilises, and then calls the `getList` method from there. As that method expects a parameter of type `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface`, this has to be built yourself first, but the advantage of this is you can tailor it to do some more filtering. Here's what I've built when I was faced with this task (you'll need to create the equivalent interface):

**Your\Module\Model\Order.php**

```
namespace Your\Module\Model;

class Order implements \Your\Module\Api\OrderInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    public $_orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    public $_searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder
     */
    public $_filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request
     */
    public $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request
    ) {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->_filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Find entities by customer ID
     * Accepts 'page' and 'show' GET params 
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function getListForCustomer($customerId) {
        $filters = [
            $this->_filterBuilder->setField('customer_id')->setValue($customerId)->create()
        ];
        $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters($filters)->create();
        $searchCriteria->setCurrentPage( $this->_request->getParam('page', 1) );
        $searchCriteria->setPageSize( $this->_request->getParam('show', 20) );
        return $this->_orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
    }    
}
```

**Your\Module\etc\webapi.xml**

```
<!-- Orders from the site -->
<route url="/V1/orders/mine" method="GET">
    <service class="Your\Module\Api\OrderInterface" method="getListForCustomer"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

You should now be able to retrieve the orders for the customer via their key automatically with **/V1/orders/mine**, without any of the search criteria parts in the URL. You may also notice that the `Order` class depends on `Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request` to retrieve GET parameters from the used URL, which can be used to get paginated results - I'm not sure if that's the proper way of doing this, but it works for me! :-)