# Need to get customer order list from Rest API

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api

[image]First I tried this endpoint /rest/V1/orders to get list of all orders history for a customer but got this error:

```
{
"message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
"parameters": {
    "resources": "Magento_Sales::sales"
}
```

Then I have used custom endpoint as mentioned in this link [How can we get customer orders history with rest API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267892/how-can-we-get-customer-orders-history-with-rest-api)

like that:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/orders/custom" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Still I'm getting the same error. I have followed this method for other APIs also and they are working fine. Just this endpoint is not working.

Comment: how are you testing the custom endpoint? Make sure  your token is working

Comment: Yes magefrm is right, you need to pass customer token and where did you put this custom webapi.xml ?

Comment: i have created custom module and inside etc folder ive created webapi.xml file and put that code in it.. ive checked it through postman with customer token...

Comment: can you include a screenshot of the postman testing

Comment: ive uploaded the screenshot pls check it

Comment: you should the `http://dev61.onlinetestingserver.com/magentotest/rest/V1/orders/custom` endpoint

Comment: can you test again using above endpoint

Comment: i have checked this endpoint also but the result is same

Comment: can you provide sample token, I will make test from my side

Comment: bro the token is valid.. ive checked this token with other apis

Comment: to check testing only bro

Comment: because error says resources for custom endpoint is still `Magento_Sales::sales` which is supposed to be self

Comment: @HasanIlyas did you run all required commands?

Comment: which command i need to execute ? please let me know

Comment: @HasanIlyas  I mean the upgrade command and all other commands after upgrade

Comment: yes i executed all these commands. .the problem is that i have tested other apis in the same way to grant access to customer and now all apis are working fine.. just this api is not working

Comment: hmm..@HasanIlyas can't really help you further. I'm not sure what's going in there but when I make test from my machine it all works well.

Comment: no problem bro .