# How can i get customer order using customer token?

Tags: orders, customer, sales-order, purchase-order

In Magento2 we have rest api to get customer orders.[Route: "/rest/V1/orders"]. 
It can used only by admin token. I want to get customer purchased order list using customer token. I couldn't find any rest api for this.
I have seen some suggestion like overriding the above api like folowing..

```
<route url="/V1/orders" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

But I dont know how to achieve this. I just learned to create new models. I m new for magento. Can you guys please help me out?

Comment: You can refer the link for same. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228815/get-all-orders-of-customer-using-customers-token-in-magento-2-api

Comment: This is the Solution mentioned there.

<route url="/V1/orders" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self" />
        </resources>
    </route>

I have created a new model and in my webapi.xml i have added above route. But i m getting response like this.

"message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "orderId",
        "fieldValue": "1"
    },

Am i missing anything? Plz Correct me.

Comment: I have seen some other solution there. I ll check with it and update here. Thank you @KirtiNariya

Answer (score 0):

Use a graphql query for customer.orders

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/schema/customer/queries/customer/#retrieve-a-summary-of-the-customers-order-history

That way you can use the customer token.